# WPF xaml DialogStyle None, Hide Title Bar

Tags: wpf, xaml, dialog, telerik, styles

In case of Window I can set :

```
    <Setter Property="AllowsTransparency" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="WindowStyle" Value="None"/>
```

How can I hide title bar in case of dialog style? In my code it is: TargetType="telerik:SchedulerDialog"